# Preloading Select2 ajax field without InitSelection

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 field that allows my users to select some entities by ajax loading. Since the source is variable, on creation my select2 field has no options but a placeholder.

On update, i want to preload my existing data inside and allow my users to change the value (by ajax) if they want, like a normal Symfony ChoiceType would.

I've found in some old topics the method "InitSelection" but it is deprecated on Select2 4.x version and i just can't understand how the remplacement method works.

Here is my current code. The defaultData is an array {id: id, text:text} :

```
function getSelect2Options(route, defaultData) {
try {
    route = Routing.generate(route);
} catch(error) {
    return {};
}

return {
    closeOnSelect: false,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
        url: route,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 500,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                query: params.term,
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
                };
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Thank you all for your help and time.